# How to download the newest build from the universal artifacts packages

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a universal artifacts package feed named 'TWI-NORA/twi-cci' How can I download the package with the newest version without hard coded style

```
 - task: DownloadPackage@1
    inputs:
      packageType: 'upack'
      feed: 'TWI-NORA/twi-cci'
      definition: '$(packageName)'
      version: '1.0.0' # something like $(latestVersion)
      extract: true
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `*` as the version of the package. Then the “download package” task will download the latest version of the package.

For example:

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
    inputs:
      packageType: 'upack'
      feed: '1'
      definition: '$(packageName)'
      version: '*'
      extract: true
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Here is a doc about [Downloading the latest version of package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#downloading-the-latest-version).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Useful to know, but why aren't pre-releases supported? eg. `1.2.0-beta.*`

Comment: i get error: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)."

Answer (score 1):

So the actual answer to this question to use

```
version: "latest"
```

This can be found in the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-package-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)