# Package fails to download when using DownloadPackage@1 task

Tags: azure, devops

I have azure artifacts which i want to download via azure pipelines. When i try with DownloadPackage@1 task, i get the following error
##[error]Failed to download package file from https://<orgname.pkgs.visualstudio.com/***/_packaging/**/maven/v1/***/***.jar got the following error:

Error: 400: Bad Request - TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 4e06e6fb-98a6-4e12-851e-69edffef100c. (DevOps Activity ID: 4E06E6FB-98A6-4E12-851E-69EDFFEF100C)

I can manually download the jar by clicking on it, but azure pipeline fails. Below is the task

```
#- task: DownloadPackage@1
#  displayName: 'Download Package'
#  inputs:
#    packageType: maven
#    feed: '49c019b9-cd70-4b8b-8a7e-2b494df50904/474b414b-58d9-4c16-9ccb-51c680d701d6'
#    view: '0ee93d90-a90b-4b44-a672-1e6e26805af0'
#    definition: '35f550fa-d319-4166-bb00-9f0a0ffe53d0'
#    version: 2.12.0.796441.1
#    files: '*'
#    downloadPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/package'
```

i tried various combinations of definiation, versions etc but no luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please let us know if you have tried with [DownloadPipelineArtifact@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I do not want to download pipeline artifact. I want to download artifacts which are already in Azure artifacts in a particular feed. So DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 will not work in my case. But DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 works when I use it in other pipelines. I cannot download packages from a feed with it though

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops#download-specific-files from this we can download specific files which are in azure artifacts.

Comment: Thank you for the cli workaround but I would like to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Few of the workaround you may follow as below:

To download the packages you can use `*` in your workaround

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
    inputs:
      packageType: 'maven'
      feed: '1'
      definition: '$(packageName)'
      version: '*'
      extract: true
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

And if you want to download specific file please make sure the you have provided all the valid name with format as mentioned in this [**`MICROSOFT DOCUMENT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops).

For more information please refer this [**`SO THREAD`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812118/how-to-download-the-newest-build-from-the-universal-artifacts-packages)